# Violin melody - 2/4 time, D major

Tags: identify-this-song, classical-music

I'm looking for a piece for violin and accompaniment (piano or orchestra, I can't remember). The violin has a tune which, as far as I can remember, goes like this.

[image: violin tune]
Neither http://www.themefinder.org/ nor musipedia.org could find it.

I expect it was a salon piece rather than something serious like a concerto. In the style of something Fritz Kreisler would play, or indeed compose. I looked around https://imslp.org/wiki/Category:Kreisler%2C_Fritz but couldn't find it there.

A curious thing is that some BBC Radio 4 programme about [Cilla Black](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cilla_Black) played a clip of her singing a song to this very tune. The song's words were, as far as I can recall, "There I was, all alone. Had no-one to guide me". I've tried Googling for this song, searching using those lyrics. Again no luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the [Serenade](https://youtu.be/jjPuxKtjdPA) No.1 Op.21 by the Dutch composer [Jonny Heykens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jonny_Heykens) (1884-1945). This is by far his most famous piece, and has been recorded in a multitude of different arrangements.

Comment: That's the one! Here's a recording of a more conventional arrangement (? Heykens's original): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jjPuxKtjdPA I must admit I'd never heard of Heykens before.

Comment: I replaced my original link with your link which is a much better arrangement, I can't find the original music, but I assume it was originally written for violin and piano.

Comment: Thanks to your identifying the composer, and given that his work is now in the public domain, I looked him up in [IMSLP](https://imslp.org/). It has two of his pieces, but, curiously, not this Serenade which is the only one he's known for.